# Фича с предпросмотром принта на wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Есть сайт https://www.giftday.ro/ на нем реализована фича с предпросмотром текста на картинке, вот конкретный пример [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли плагины для worpress для реализации данной идеи? Или есть готовые решения на других конструкторах?